# iPad UIActionSheet in modalView problem

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, modal-dialog, uiactionsheet

I'm using an ActionSheet in a modalView, in iPad.
I'm showing it from a UIBarButton, on a navController.
First problem: if i click 10 times, it show's 10 actionSheet, which is a problem.

Second problem: on the right item of the navBar, there's a DONE button.
When i click on the actionSheet button, and the actionsheet appears, and I then click on the DONE button, the modalView is dismissed, and the actionsheet keeps on screen, and then the app crash.

Code to show the actionsheet:

```
UIActionSheet *iPadActionButton = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle: @""
                                                              delegate: self
                                                     cancelButtonTitle: nil
                                                destructiveButtonTitle: nil
                                                     otherButtonTitles: @"option 1", @"option 2", @"option ", nil];

iPadActionButton.destructiveButtonIndex = 2;
[iPadActionButton showFromBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem animated:YES];
[iPadActionButton setTag:200];
[iPadActionButton release];
```

Any ideas on how to resolve these issues?

Rui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep a reference to the UIActionSheet as a class property.

In your header:

```
@interface ClassName: UIViewController {
    UIActionSheet *iPadActionButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActionSheet *iPadActionButton;
```

That will do two things:

1) Allow you to check to see if it's already visible with the [iPadActionButton visible] property.

2) Allow you to properly dispose of it in viewWillDisappear:anaimated: